# css text-align center not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a canvas and an overlapping image. On chrome and firefox the center-align property works perfectly fine, however it doesn't work on IE. The canvas is not centered, but the image is. I have tried alternative ways for centering both the canvas and image, but nothing works.

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/oetiker/RrdGraphJS) for displaying interactive RRD Graphs. It uses the [qooxdoo](https://www.qooxdoo.org/) framework.
The canvas is created by this library, is that a possible reason for it?
(FYI: the canvas is created in the rrdGraphPng.js file in method: __addCanvas())

My goal is to overlap the canvas & image and center them horizontally.

This is my html (after javascript has added the canvas):

```
<div id="graph-content">
   <div id="ctrl">
     <div>
        <canvas draggable="false" unselectable="true" width="700" height="330"></canvas>
        <img id="img" data-src-template=".." data-qx-class="rrdGraphPng" unselectable="true" draggable="false" src=".." />
     </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
    div{
        display: block;
    }

    #ctrl{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #img {
        width: 700px;
        height: 330px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 700px;
        height: 330px;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: url(http://../rrdtoolgraph/RrdGraphJS/public//MoveCursor.cur), move;
    }
```

This is what is generated in the browser:

```
div {
   display: block;
}

#ctrl {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Canvas */
element.style {
   position: absolute;
   cursor: url(http://../rrdtoolgraph/RrdGraphJS/public//MoveCursor.cur), move;
   width: 700px;
   height: 330px;
}

/* this is not present in Firefox and IE11 */
canvas[Attributes Style] {
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

/* Image */
element.style {
   height: 330px;
   width: 700px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#img {
   width: 700px;
   height: 330px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: auto;
}

/* this is not present in Firefox and IE11 */
img[Attributes Style] {
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MerveSahin/89bv9eob/). It does not run properly, because it needs access to resources, that cannot be managed over jsfiddle.

Comment: please add a working snippet or jsfiddle.

Comment: add to canvas css line `display: inline-block;`

Comment: It probably has to do with different styles that browsers implement on your HTML elements.

Comment: @MysterX does not work on IE11

Comment: @Vishnu I created a jsfiddle, but it doesn't run properly, since it requires resources, that cannot be accessed simply over jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive experimenting I finally found a solution, that works on all browsers. It's not the best solution, but for now the only one:

```
    .title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    div {
        display: block;
    }

    #ctrl{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #zoom-image {
        width: 700px;
        height: 330px;
    }

    canvas {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first `div` child of `#ctrl`; as a block element, it will render as 100% width. You should not try to center block elements, using inline elements centering techniques (like `text-align`).

It's always easy to center a block element if you have a fixed width (in your case 700px). Set the width of the element and then set its left and right margins to `auto`.

Add the following selector to your css:

```
#ctrl > div {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```